# Gnuplot histogram x logscale

Tags: gnuplot, histogram, scaling

I'm using gnuplot in a bash script to draw several things.
For this special graphic, I need to print the amount of matrices (y axis) with the matrix size as the x-axis.
As the distribution can be pretty sparsed, I want to use a logscale for x and y. It works great with y, but gnuplot tells me I can't have a logscale for the x-axis when I'm using histogram style.

Any ideas to debug this? or on how to present the results using a similar way?

```
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1
set style fill solid border -1
set logscale xy
plot '$res/histo-$ld-$lr-$e-$r' using 2:xtic(1) title 'Run'
```

The error is :

```
line 0: Log scale on X is incompatible with histogram plots
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit : btw, I was using gnuplot 4.4 patchlevel 4 and just updated to the newest version  (i.e. 4.6 patchlevel 5)

Comment: Please provide some data samples. Gnuplot histograms work a bit differently from what you might think. The x-axis isn't numeric. In your case the value in the first row, second column is placed at an x-value of `0` with the y-value taken from the second column and a manual label taken from the first column, first row. The values of the second row are placed at x=1 etc. You could try using the `boxes` plotting style, which is used with a 'conventional' x-axis and which might support a logscale in x.

Comment: Here is a data sample :

`X Y
1 1000
2 300
5 150
20 10
135 3`

What you're saying is that by default the histogram x-axis isn't numeric? That would explain why I can't have a logscale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gnuplot histograms work a bit differently from what you might think. The x-axis isn't numeric. In your case the value in the first row, second column is placed at an x-value of 0 with the y-value taken from the second column and a manual label taken from the first column, first row. The values of the second row are placed at x=1 etc.

You can try using the boxes plotting style, which is used with a 'conventional' x-axis and supports a logscale in x:

```
set logscale xy
set offset 0,0,1,1
set boxwidth 0.9 relative
set style fill solid noborder
plot 'data.dat' with boxes
```

With the data file `data.dat`

```
1 1000
2 300 
5 150 
20 10 
135 3
```

this gives the result (with 4.6.5):

[image]

In order to have a fixed boxwidth and a varying box distance, you can use a third column to specify a box width as percentage of the x-value:

```
set logscale xy
set offset 0,0,1,1
set style fill solid noborder
plot 'data.dat' using 1:2:($1*0.5) with boxes
```

[image]

Putting the actual values on the x-axis works as follows:

```
set logscale xy
set offset 0,0,1,1
set style fill solid noborder
plot 'data.dat' using 1:2:($1*0.5):xtic(1) with boxes
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, after a little bit of work I ended up with pretty much the same thing. However I find that the varying width makes the graph ugly. Any way to keep the logscale and the fixed width?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Well I guess I'm still having issues ...

plot 'data.dat' using 1:2:3 with boxes works fine (like the image above. I have an awk script which computes the size). However, I want the x-axis labels to be the x values (1 2 5 20 135). plot 'data.dat' using 2:xtic(1) with boxes does that but with varying sizes. and plot 'data.dat' using 2:xtic(1):3 does something very strange ( boxes' size column is on x-axis, and value 1 is on y axis !)

Comment: The `xtic(1)` part must be the last entry in the `using` statement, e.g. `using 1:2:3:xtic(1)`, see my edit.

Comment: I don't seem to understand completely the `using` statement ... Anyway, thanks a lot, this is finally working as I expected !